# "serialport" node module version error message confusing

Tags: node.js

Does the following node error mean I need to upgrade the serialport module, or downgrade nodejs, or something else?   (It used to work until I updated ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04)

```
Error: The module '../node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build/Release/bindings.node' 
was compiled against a different Node.js version using 
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. This version of Node.js requires 
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

I have tried:

```
rm package-lock.json;
rm -rf node_modules;
npm install
npm rebuild
npm install serialport --build-from-source
sudo npm install serialport --unsafe-perm --build-from-source
```

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Completely removed nodejs npm, reinstalled, ran nodejs main.js  and then installed packages as necessary using npm.  Works now.

Comment: `npm rebuild` should have taken care of it.  Sounds like something got stuck somehow.  Was your module installed globally by chance?

Comment: Possibly, I think I had at some point installed node with sudo in a different location at some point in the past, and it was hanging on to those definitions. I searched and removed any instances I could find and then reinstalled and that solved it. Thanks.